# How to find the divergence rate of a recursive sequence defined by $s_n = s_{n-1}(1 + c_n s_{n-1})$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, recursion, divergent-series

So my question is regarding a sequence of numbers defined recursively by $s_n = s_{n-1}(1 + c_n s_{n-1})$, where $(c_n)$ is some sequence of positive numbers when $s_0 = \epsilon > 0$ is small (how small may depend on $(c_n)$). I know if $c_n$ is summable, then $s_n$ converges if $s_0$ is sufficiently small. When $c_n$ is not summable, then I believe $s_n$ doesn't converge, but I don't know how its divergence rate relates to $c_n$. If $s_0$ is small, it seems to diverge slightly faster than the sum of $c_n$ but I don't know how to get more precise than that.

Comment: What do you mean by divergence rate?

Comment: Asymptotically, is it in $O(\sum_k^n c_k)$ or something like that. I'm looking for an upper bound of the growth rate of $s_n$ in terms of $c_n$. Ideally, I'd like as tight as possible of an upper bound.

Comment: It is definitely not in that range. Now, are you asking about bounds of the type "for which $A_n$ there exists $s_0>0$ such that $s_n\le A_n$ for all $n$" or you need something more precise than that?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. More precise is better, but some upper bound dependent on $c_n$ that works for $s_0$ sufficiently small is what I want.

Comment: May I also assume that $c_n$ is (eventually) decreasing, or I'd better not?

Comment: Yes that's fine.

Comment: Of course, I'm not the one giving the bounty, so maybe you should see what Antonia Vargas says too.

Comment: It's more important to see what you need. The last question: may I also assume that $c_n$ is regular in the sense that $c_{n+1}>\delta c_n$ with some fixed $\delta>0$?

Comment: Yeah I think that would be fine for my application.

Comment: Then the answer seems (no warranty yet) to be that you can guarantee any bound of the type $s_n\le \exp(c2^n)$ with $c>0$, but nothing better than that. I'll check the details now and, if everything is fine, post the argument.

Comment: Hm.. I was hoping it would be slower than that, but if it's what the math says I have to go with it. That is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the double exponential lower bound.

Note that $c_n=\frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_{n-1}^2}$. Let $K>0$. The sum of the right hand sides can then be viewed as the left Riemann sum for the function $x\mapsto \frac 1{x^2}$ on $[s_0,+\infty)$ corresponding to the partition with the nodes $s_n$. If we had $s_{n}\le (K+1)s_{n-1}$ for all $n$, that Riemann sum would be comparable to $\int_{s_0}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}<+\infty$, which contradicts the divergence of $\sum_n c_n$. Thus, we have $c_n s_{n-1}>K$ somewhere. Since $c_{n+k}\ge c_n\delta^k$ (regularity), we then have the inequality
$$
t_k=c_ns_{n+k}\ge \delta^k(c_n s_{n+k-1})^2=\delta^k t_{k-1}^2
$$
for $k\ge 0$. Here $t_{-1}>K$. If we replace the inequalities by identities,
the solution to this recursion will be
$$
T_k=K^{2^k}\delta^{k+2(k-1)+2^2(k-2)+\dots+2^{k-1}}
$$
However $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} 2^{-m}m=\sigma<+\infty$, so we get $t_k>T_k\ge [K\delta^\sigma]^{2^k}$, which is a double exponential growth if the product in brackets is greater than $1$.

To get the upper bound, it is enough to assume that $c_n\le C-1$ and start with $s_0=1$. Then we have $(Cs_n)\le (Cs_{n-1})^2$, so $s_n\le C^{2^n}$. Now, by choosing $s_0$ small enough, we can keep $s_n$ below $1$ for any time $n_0$ we want, so we can shift this bound to $C^{2^{n-n_0}}=\exp(2^{-n_0}\log C\cdot 2^n)$. The rest should be clear.

Comment: This looks very good. I'm not sure where you got the inequality $c_n s_{n+k} \ge \delta^k (c_n s_{n+k-1})^2$ though. Also the sum for $\sigma$ is 2 but that doesn't change your proof.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp It is just $s_{n+k}=s_{n+k-1}(1+c_{n+k}s_{n+k-1})\ge c_{n+k}s_{n+k-1}^2\ge \delta^k c_ns_{n+k-1}^2$

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I got there, but yeah we also have $c_n \ge c_n^2$ since it's less than one (in the limit).

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Nope. You just multiply both sides by $c_n$.

Comment: Oh right. Wow, I'm just a little slow today I guess.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp No problem. Feel free to ask as many questions as you wish :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Showing the divergence.** It is easy to show (by induction) $(s_n)$ is a positive sequence.

**Proposition 1** $(s_n)$ is ascending.

Since $(c_n)$ is positive, then
$$s_n-s_{n-1} = s_{n-1}(1 + c_n s_{n-1})-s_{n-1}=s_{n-1}^2c_n\geq 0 \tag{1}$$
or
$$s_n\geq s_{n-1}$$

---

**Proposition 2** $$s_n-s_{n-1} \geq \varepsilon^2 c_n \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and because $(s_n)$ is ascending
$$s_n-s_{n-1} = s_{n-1}^2c_n\overset{(1)}{\geq} s_{n-2}^2c_n\geq ... \geq s_0^2c_n=\varepsilon^2 c_n$$

---

**Proposition 3** If $\sum\limits_{n=1} c_n = \infty$ then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=\infty$.

$$s_n = s_n-s_0+s_0=(s_n-s_{n-1})+(s_{n-1}-s_0)+s_0=\\
(s_n-s_{n-1})+(s_{n-1}-s_{n-2})+(s_{n-2}-s_0)+s_0=...\\
...=s_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(s_k-s_{k-1})\overset{(2)}{\geq} s_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \varepsilon^2 c_k=\\
s_0+\varepsilon^2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^n c_k$$
Taking the limit, leads to the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! I am also strongly interested in precisely how fast $s_n$ diverges, so I'll wait to see if anyone can get a more precise estimate than divergence at least as fast as than $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k$

Comment: Sure, I'll see if I can improve the answer in the meantime ...

Comment: OK thanks. I'm specifically hoping for an upper bound on the growth rate, because for my application I have another sequence $a_n$ that goes to $0$ and I want to know whether or not $a_n s_n$ converges.